# Site Collections and Content Database

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Does every Site Collection in SharePoint (2010) have its own Content Database (by default)? need some information, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by default. If you go to the Content Databases section of Central Administration you'll see two properties associated with a content database. One is an alert level that will notify you when that many sites are now on that content database, the other is a physical maximum number of sites that's allowed on that content database.

It is possible to create a content database and set its' limit to 1 so it is dedicated to a site collection, but out of the box, the default values are quite high.

Edit:

Note that if you need to gather quick information about how many sites are on which database, you can use the Get-SPContentDatabase cmdlet in PowerShell as `Get-SPContentDatabase | Select Name, CurrentSiteCount` to show the counts for every DB in the farm. If you need to identify what content database a given site is in, you can use `Get-SPContentDatabase -Site http(s)://path/to/site/collection`.

Comment: thanks, I am newbie on SharePoint need some recomendations for migrating of our repository. We have a data repository on our file server which is 0.5 terabyte. we want to migrate it to sharepoint how do you recoment it. do we need to create different web application or it is enought to have one web application and several site collections. thanks agian.

Comment: When you say "data repository", is it SharePoint content already that you're mounting in SharePoint, or is it non-SharePoint content that you need to migrate into SharePoint. Those are two wildly different scenarios.

Comment: the data repository is not Sharepoint content. it is file server (folders and files). When we migrate it, do we need to create different web application or it is enought to have one web application and several site collections. thanks agian

Comment: So in some cases it makes sense to isolate things out. It's pretty rare that you'd want a SharePoint database that big, so you'd need to do some planning around capacity and scaling, then you'd need a third party tool to bring that content into SharePoint.

Comment: Yes, I know these, so you mean I need to create several Web applications. what is the recomendations?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint will not create additional content database unless you request it though Central Administration or PowerShell

When you create a Site Collection though the UI SharePoint will put it into one of the Content databases trying to even out the load. If you create a site collection through PowerShell (or code) you have the option of specifying the content database to use

You can move a Site Collection to another content database using PowerShell if you want